# Visual Studio Code's Solidity extension shows unecessary warnings/errors

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, visual-studio-code

I am using Juan Blanco's Solidity extension for VSC. I am noticing it is showing just too many warnings everywhere, including the OpenZeppelin contracts in the `node_modules` folder. Is there any alternative to it? Or any way to suppress all the unnecessary warnings? Having a bunch of yellow underlines and red highlighted folders everywhere is kind of distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature of the extension that you are using is that it enables [Solium (now Ethlint)](https://github.com/duaraghav8/Ethlint). This is a linter that checks your code for errors and warnings, such as `no-trailing-whitespace: Line contains trailing whitespace`.

The best solution is to fix these warnings in your code, since the warnings are suggestions to follow best practices when writing Solidity. Code that follows the [Solidity style guide](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html) should have no warnings like this.

If you want to remove some of these warnings without changing the code, you will need to edit your `settings.json` in VS Code. Within this file you can add the following line:

```
"solidity.soliumRules": {
}
```

In here, you can add rules that you want to ignore. For example, if you want to ignore the trailing whitespace warning, your `settings.json` file should look as follows:

```
"solidity.soliumRules": {
    "no-trailing-whitespace": "off"
}
```